# ManyToOne mapping with Doctrine and undefined index warnings

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this, but I can't fathom what's going on. I have an entity called a `Payment` and two other entities called `User` and `Household`.

A `User` has many `Payment`s and and a `Household` has many `Payment`s. This is all mapped as unidirectional manyToOne relationships of the `Payment` using YAML, like this (hopefully this is in line with the guidance at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-one-unidirectional) -

```
Payment:
  type: entity
  table: payments
  id:
    _id:
      type: integer
      column: payment_id
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
    manyToOne:
    _user:
      targetEntity: Application_Model_User
      joinColumn:
        name: user_id
        referencedColumnName: payment_id
    _household:
      targetEntity: Application_Model_Household
      joinColumn:
        name: household_id
        referencedColumnName: payment_id
```

Database wise, I have three tables, `users`, `payments` and `households`. The `payments` table has (in addition to it's primary key) two columns called `user_id` and `household_id`, which correspond the to primary keys of the other two tables.

The problem is that when I try to persist a new `Payment` I get an error back from mySql telling me that the `user_id` column of `payments` cannot be null. Some digging has established that doctrine is supplying `null` for both `user_id` and `household_id` in the INSERT statement. The object graph is definitely correct.

In addition, I get the following warnings:

```
Notice: Undefined index: payment_id in [..]/library/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php on line 511

Notice: Undefined index: in [..]/library/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php on line 511

Notice: Undefined index: payment_id in [..]/library/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php on line 511

Notice: Undefined index: in [..]/library/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php on line 511
```

I've established that the `payment_id` in question is coming from the `referencedColumnName`s in my mapping, and that the index is undefined because the array doctrine is searching contains the fields from the *opposite* side of the relationship, i.e. the `Household` or the `User`. But surely it shouldn't be? I think I've followed the guide, but I can't make it work.

I'm using Zend Framework, if it helps, but there's nothing special going on my code. I'm pretty sure it's a mapping problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've only worked with Doctrine + Symfony2, but I think your referencedColumnName should just be "id", not payment_id, because you need to explain the foreign key relationship.

`payment.household_id` --references--> `household.id`.

In Symfony2 there is an 'inversedBy' property for Doctrine, which is used to map the column in the other table that would represent the payment_id.

A snippet of code from a Symfony2 Mapping:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="kurtfunai\WalkthroughBundle\Entity\Group", inversedBy="members")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="fk_group_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $group;
```

In your case it would need altered to something like this:

```
_user:
  targetEntity: Application_Model_User
  joinColumn:
    name: user_id
    referencedColumnName: <USERS_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_NAME>
_household:
  targetEntity: Application_Model_Household
  joinColumn:
    name: household_id
    referencedColumnName: <HOUSEHOLDS_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_COLUMN_NAME>
```

(Replace with the appropriate column names)

Comment: The primary key column in the payments table *is* called 'payment_id' - so that's what the referencedColumnName should be, right?

Comment: No, in this case you're mapping the foreign key relationship between the payment and the household tables. If your primary key on your payments table is `payments.payment_id`, that is fine (though I thought Doctrine enforced having id as the primary key name) - But the payments primary key is not needed for this. 

What you're actually mapping is the FK relationship, so in this case `payments.household_id` is referencing the id column of your households table (which I will assume is named similarly: `households.household_id`.

Comment: I've edited my answer to illustrate what I am saying more clearly

Comment: It works! Thanks very much, I was approaching the referenced column from the wrong side, I think. Also, for the record, Doctrine is happy for you to call your primary keys whatever you like, though the default is indeed 'id'.